# counting by criteria in vba code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have multiple item form based on a parameter query (between date `a` and date `b`). I want that the unbounded field `test` at the bottom  of the form  will contain the count of all the records where the field `days` is bigger then 5.

I wrote following simple code but get 0 as an answer.

```
Private Sub test_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim n As Integer

    For n = 1 To 10
        If days.Value > 5 Then
            test = test + 1
        End If
    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Because `test` variable is never used to return count of days. BTW: What is `days`? A collection?

Comment: Seems to me you're not referencing all the items in the form, and not updating anything with the `test` value as `Maciej Los` pointed out. And where is `test` dimensioned and as what data type? I strongly recommend using `Option explicit` from now on.

Comment: What about [DCount](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dcount.php) function?

Comment: I tried the fuction Dcount to count the  records in the query. but becouse it is a parameter query ( between date a and date b) i need to path the parameters to the query, how do i path the parameters.

Comment: The form is also based on the same parameter query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test = DCount("any_field","parameter_Query","days > 5")
```

Where `any_field` is literally any field in your query, `parameter_Query` is the query you use to get your data and `days > 5` is the condition to return just the fields that meet that condition. The aggregate function `DCount()` does the count of the returned fields. I hope this helps.